# Behavior of a pipe after a fork()

Tags: c, unix, fork, pipe

When reading about pipes in Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, I noticed that after a fork the parent can `close()` the read end of a pipe and it doesn't close the read end for the child.  When a process forks, does its file descriptors get retained?

What I mean by this is that before the fork the pipe read file descriptor had a retain count of 1, and after the fork 2.  When the parent closed its read side the fd went to 1 and is kept open for the child.  Is this essentially what is happening?  Does this behavior also occur for regular file descriptors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As one can read on the man page about [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork):

> The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's file
>   descriptors. Each of the child's file
>   descriptors shall refer to the same
>   open file description with the
>   corresponding file descriptor of the
>   parent.

So yes, the child have exact copy of parent's file descriptors and that refers to all of them, including open files.

Comment: ...unless you do some trickery with http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_atfork.html (which you shouldn't, that's not what it's there for)

Comment: Sure, but what you posted is not a `fork()` but a variation of it.

Comment: No, I mean that `pthread_atfork` can change the program's actions at `fork` time to (for example) include closing file descriptors.  But by default that doesn't happen, and it's a strange thing to be abusing that interface anyhow.

Comment: But what happens with you fork() twice and then write to children. Which will read them? Both? The first to call read? What if they are both currently blocked at a read?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, and yes (the same applies to all file descriptors, including things like sockets).

In a `fork()` call, the child gets its own seperate copy of each file descriptor, that each act like they had been created by `dup()`.  A `close()` only closes the specific file descriptor that was passed - so for example if you do `n2 = dup(n); close(n);`, the file (pipe, socket, device...) that `n` was referring to remains open - the same applies to file descriptors duplicated by a `fork()`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a fork duplicates all open file descriptors.

So for a typical pipe, a 2 slot array (int fd[2]), fd[0] is the same for the parent and child, and so is fd[1].

You can create a pipe without forking at all, and read/write to yourself by using fd[0] and fd[1] in one process.